# File uploads without $_FILES

Tags: php

Is it possible in PHP to configure it to somehow not save files to disk at all? As a matter of fact, the best thing would be to get the script going before even reading the entire POST body. (Keeping my hopes high ;))

Comment: Do you need this for one file, or multiple files? Would limiting yourself to one file be an option? Where will the file come from, a form?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off file uploads via a configuration setting in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.file-uploads

Comment: This is not what he means: He wants file uploads to work without temporary files.

Comment: it is even worse. he wants to directly catch the upload stream without buffering it into the tempfile. would be pretty nice for verry big fileuploads.

Answer (score 0):

PHP needs a place to temporarily store the files content for you to be able to interact with it through PHP - although, you don't have to do anything else other then access the temporary file to get the data:

```
$content = file_get_contents($_FILES["user_file"]["tmp_name"]);
```

From here on you can manipulate with the files content without having to move the uploaded file to another location before accessing it.

Comment: that's exactly what he was not asking for. he want's to know if there is a possebility of NOT doing it the normal "save it into a temp then let php work with it" way

Comment: I know and I was just stating the obvious and at the same time adding an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP `PUT` requests to directly upload a file. PHP will not handle the upload directly (e.g. set it up in $_FILES). Instead, you have to read the raw bytes from the `php://input` pseudo-url and from there can do whatever you want.

There's some details and examples [here](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/features.file-upload.put-method.php).